# android java.util.Array List versus java.util.List

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I have a strange error message when I want to use the result of a Server query and an offline SQLite request.

Error message in Android Studio:

```
Incompatible types:
Required: java.util.Array.list
Found: java.util.List
```

ArrayList is declared: `private ArrayList<Jamky> campojamkyList;`
and assigned: `campojamkyList = new ArrayList<>();`

The array returned is in both cases the same:

```
campolist = {ArrayList@1235} size = 18
0 = {Jamky@1235 }
 campoid = 23
 delka = 330
.......
```

When I want to assign the result of the SqLite Query 
    `campolist = db.getAllJamky(campo);`
I get the error message.

Does anybody has a clue why this strange behaviour occurs or some hints how to maybe convert the util.list to an Array.list?

Comment: Why not change your getAllJamky function to return the proper type instead?

Comment: The solution that I found was really simple. I just changed private ArrayList<Jamky> campojamkyList to private List<Jamky> campojamkyList and it is working.

Answer (score 3):

Because `List` is not a class it is an interface. `ArrayList` implements List.

For a method, you better use a List as a return so you not restricting the method for further usage (to a LinkedList for example).

So, you need to change `db.getAllJamky(campo)` to something like this:

```
public List<YourObject> getAllJamky(YourObject yourObject) {
  List<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
  // the implementation
  ...
  return list;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, but the problem was the declaration of the  list.